# How to lock a shared DB resource between machines

Tags: c#

I am developing a software that is going to reside on multiple machines. the DB is shared.
I need each machine to grab a unique resource (row) from the DB and lock it.

My question is how do I take care of that? because each machine reads the same rows, and racing can occur.

Basically I think its the same as threads but the difference is that i cannot share a shared resource between them...

how is this solvable?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by locking a row ? only relevant machine can modify it ?

Comment: Yes. I want one machine to "capture" the row, do some work while can't machines won't work on that row

Comment: Why do you want a locking mechanism in the first place? have you considered using transactions? you might find this link helpful http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I solved by writing my own locking procedure at database level.

Basically I added a column which I called "SessionLock" and was a GUID.

Whenever I make a database call which requires locking, I use a stored procedure to emulate test-and-set (I use an Update if SessionLock is not null and check whether the rows returned is equal to the amount of rows which I requested to be locked). I then perform some work on the rows and unlock them after I'm done.

Now databases themselves have their own locking, so you might not need this much complication. But this way you have complete control over the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additonal column to that table which could store a machine specific unique value, for example machine name `Environment.MachineName`. each machine will update the specific row with its own machine name when it reads the table very first time. By doing this you can make sure each row can be altered by the specific machine only.

- When a machine reading resource table very first time, it will get
  the first record which doesnt have a machine name. (Preventing from
  overriting row other machine have locked).
- And it will update that row's unique column with its machine name.
- Whenever a machine wants to update a row check if the machine name of
  that row and requested machine is same.
- Once all the operations are completed, clear the machine name from
  particular row(Releasing the resource).

Comment: But what promises me that they won't override each other?

Comment: What do you mean by overriding each other ? Can you elaborate your requirement ?

Comment: I have fixed "resources". each resource is a row in the DB and each machine can capture one, work on it, and release. but i cant have 2 machines work on the same resource. hence i need to lock it somehow

Comment: @Himberjack Still my solution should solve your problem. check updated answer.

Comment: @Coder, you might want to add something regarding the case where a record has been locked and not released due to network/system failure.

Answer (score 0):

All serious database systems have a mechanism for locking rows and/or tables. Before you implement some homebrewn locking yourself, check out what your DBMS already brings to the table.

You didn't mention what DBMS you use, so you will have to do the googling yourself.
Start with "*database* lock" and see where it leads you.